# How to swap the position of the 2 buttons by dragging in PyQt5

Tags: button, pyqt5

I am trying to make small program in Python,using PyQt5.The program will as have many button has arranged neatly.When dragging one of the buttons to another button, you can swap their positions while the buttons are still arranged neatly.I tried many ways, but in the end the buttons couldn’t be arranged neatly.What should I do to achieve this effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `QEventFilter`.

Simple version:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

class Filter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._pressed = None
        self._drag = False

    def setDragMode(self, active):
        """ When drag mode activated buttons are not clickable (mouse events are filtered) """
        self._drag = active

    def setLayout(self, layout):
        self._layout = layout
        for i in range(layout.count()):
            item = layout.itemAt(i)
            if item.widget():
                item.widget().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        
        if not self._drag:
            return False

        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if isinstance(obj, QPushButton):
                self._pressed = obj
                return True

        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            button = self._pressed
            layout = self._layout
            if button is None:
                return True
            
            pos = obj.mapToParent(event.pos())
            index = layout.indexOf(button)
            geometry = button.geometry()
            if pos.x() < geometry.topLeft().x():
                if index - 1 >= 0:
                    prev = layout.itemAt(index - 1).widget().geometry()
                    if prev.topRight().x() > pos.x():
                        layout.insertWidget(index - 1, button)
            elif pos.x() > geometry.topRight().x():
                if index + 1 < layout.count():
                    next_ = layout.itemAt(index + 1).widget().geometry()
                    if next_.topLeft().x() < pos.x():
                        layout.insertWidget(index + 1, button) 
            return True

        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            self._pressed = None
            return True
            
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    buttons = [QPushButton("button {}".format(i)) for i in range(5)]
    for button in buttons:
        layout.addWidget(button)
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()

    filter_ = Filter()
    filter_.setLayout(layout)
    filter_.setDragMode(True)

    app.exec_()
```

More intuitive and interactive version:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

class Overlay(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._widget = None
        self._pressPos = None
        self._topLeftPos = None
        self._movePos = None
        self._pixmap = None

    def setDragWidget(self, widget, pressPos, topLeftPos):
        self._widget = widget
        self._pressPos = pressPos
        self._movePos = pressPos
        self._topLeftPos = topLeftPos
        self._pixmap = widget.grab()

    def mouseMoved(self, pos):
        self._movePos = pos
        self.update()

    def mouseReleased(self):
        self._pixmap = None
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self._pixmap is None:
            return

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self._topLeftPos + self._movePos - self._pressPos, self._pixmap)

def swap_widgets(layout, index1, index2):
    if index1 == index2:
        return
    widget1 = layout.itemAt(index1).widget()
    widget2 = layout.itemAt(index2).widget()
    layout.insertWidget(index1, widget2)
    layout.insertWidget(index2, widget1)

class Filter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._pressed = None
        self._drag = False
        self._overlay = None

    def setDragMode(self, active):
        """ When drag mode activated buttons are not clickable (mouse events are filtered) """
        self._drag = active

    def setLayout(self, layout):
        self._layout = layout
        for i in range(layout.count()):
            item = layout.itemAt(i)
            if item.widget():
                item.widget().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        
        if not self._drag:
            return False

        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if isinstance(obj, QPushButton):
                self._pressed = obj
                parent = obj.parent()
                overlay = Overlay(parent)
                overlay.setGeometry(parent.rect())
                pressPos = obj.mapToParent(event.pos())
                overlay.setDragWidget(obj, pressPos, obj.geometry().topLeft())
                overlay.show()
                self._overlay = overlay
            return True

        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            button = self._pressed
            layout = self._layout
            if button is None:
                return True
            pos = obj.mapToParent(event.pos())
            overlay = self._overlay
            if overlay is not None:
                overlay.mouseMoved(pos)
            return True
            
        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            overlay = self._overlay
            button = self._pressed
            layout = self._layout
            if overlay is not None:
                overlay.mouseReleased()
                overlay.hide()
            pos = obj.mapToParent(event.pos())
            index1 = layout.indexOf(button)
            for index2 in range(layout.count()):
                widget = layout.itemAt(index2).widget()
                if widget is None:
                    continue
                if widget.geometry().contains(pos):
                    swap_widgets(layout, index1, index2)
                    break
            self._pressed = None
            return True

        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    buttons = [QPushButton("button {}".format(i)) for i in range(5)]
    for button in buttons:
        layout.addWidget(button)
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()

    filter_ = Filter()
    filter_.setLayout(layout)
    filter_.setDragMode(True)

    app.exec_()
```